# Is there a way of using geom_ribbon with values for xmin and xmax?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The standard way of using geom_ribbon is to have a fixed value of x and some values for ymin and ymax. The input would be a dataframe like df_x:

```
library(tidyverse)

# This works

df_x <- tibble(
    x = c(1, 2),
    ymax = c(0.5, 0.8),
    ymin = c(0.4, 0.3)
) 

ggplot(df_x) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))
```

However, I have a dataset that contains the inverse: a fixed value of y and some values for xmin and xmax. However, geom_ribbon does not accept data presented in this way.

```
# This should produce an identical graph

df_y <- tibble(
    y = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8),
    xmax = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
    xmin = c(2, 1, 1, 2)
)

ggplot(df_y) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, y = y))
```

Is there a way of plotting df_y directly, without performing a transformation on df_y to make it into essentially df_x?

Comment: How about `coord_flip()`?  Like `ggplot(df_y) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = xmin, ymax = xmax, x = y)) + coord_flip()`.  I often use package **ggstance** for "horizontal" geoms, but I don't see a ribbon as one of the options.

Comment: Thanks for this! The coord_flip() solution would be a good short-term fix, but since that might cause problems further on (axis labels, for example), I would rather have something that didn't flip the axes. I will investigate ggstance though, that looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question as I was looking to use `geom_ribbon` for something myself. I'm not sure if `ggplot` has changed since you originally asked this over 2 years ago, but both plots using `df_x` and `df_y` produced the same output for me (aside from each missing an axis label on the axis which has the `*min` and `*max` values supplied to it).

```
library(tidyverse)

# This works

df_x <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2),
  ymax = c(0.5, 0.8),
  ymin = c(0.4, 0.3)
) 

ggplot(df_x) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))
```

[image]

```
df_y <- tibble(
  y = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8),
  xmax = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
  xmin = c(2, 1, 1, 2)
)

ggplot(df_y) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, y = y))
```

[image]

I would also disagree with your first statement

> The standard way of using geom_ribbon is to have a fixed value of x and some values for ymin and ymax.

I think rather than 'standard way' you might mean 'more common'. [The help page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html) explains that `geom_ribbon` guesses the orientation of the ribbon based on mappings you provide; it's probably obvious based on which axis is supplied with `*min` and `*max` parameters, and which has a fixed value. Alternatively, you can include `geom_ribbon(orientation = 'x')` or `geom_ribbon(orientation = 'y')` if it has not automatically (or correctly) assumed which axis you want to plot the ribbon relative to, which may be a solution for someone with a similar problem.

However, you will get an error if you try and force it to the wrong orientation; in the example using `df_y` above, if you supply `orientation = 'x'`, you get `Error: Either ymin or ymax must be given as an aesthetic`.